# Ordering differences between Postgres instances on different machines (same locale)

Tags: postgresql, locale, postgresql-9.1

I have two Postgres 9.1 instances: one local, installed via Postgres.app on OS X, and one remote, on Heroku. I've ensured that `lc_collate` is `en_US.UTF-8` on both machines but am still seeing different behavior between the two.

On my local instance, `SELECT 'i' > 'N'` returns `t` whereas remotely it returns `f`. Given that I've already checked `lc_*` on both systems, what explains the difference I'm seeing?

Comment: But `select 'i' > 'n'` and `select 'I' > 'N'` both behave as expected, right?

Comment: Yes, `select 'i' > 'n'` and `select 'I' > 'N'` are false in all cases.

Comment: Also, if I specify collation as "C" or "POSIX" I get consistent behavior, but not with collation "en_US".

Comment: So you're saying that one of them is case sensitive and one of them isn't. Have you look at the `lc_ctype` settings? You can use `show X` to see the `X` setting from within `psql`.

Comment: Yep, all 6 `lc_*` settings on both machines are set to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: It's looking increasingly like OS X's en_US.UTF-8 locale is off, but I will continue looking into it and report back.

Comment: `SELECT 'i' > 'N'` is true for me on OSX, PostgreSQL 9.0.1, and en_CA.UTF-8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the point of view of Unicode, the case ordering is a customization.
Excerpt from http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10:

> Case Ordering. Some dictionaries and authors collate uppercase before
>   lowercase while others use the reverse, so that preference needs to be
>   customizable. Sometimes the case ordering is mandated by the
>   government, as in Denmark. Often it is simply a customization or user
>   preference.

Mac OS X simply has a different case ordering than the OS used by Heroku. On Mac OS X:

```
$ LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 sort << EOF
> i
> N
> EOF
```

produces:

> N
>   i

The exact same command and same data on Ubuntu 12.04 produces:

> i
>   N

This has none to do with PostgreSQL, except for the fact that it uses the OS for collation, so these unfortunate discrepancies between different OS impact databases.

### PostgreSQL 10 and ICU

Starting with version 10, PostgreSQL may use [collations provided by the ICU library](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/collation.html), for servers compiled with [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). These collations can sort consistently across operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation -- this is what I discovered as well. Given that en_US.UTF-8 is different across OS's, is there a standard practice for ensuring common sorting across systems?

Comment: @jredburn Alas, nothing reliable. It's a real pain, and one of the reasons I hope the dormant proposal to integrate ICU into PostgreSQL goes ahead, as mentioned here: http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/10/natural-sorting-example-of-utility-of.html

Comment: I'm not aware of a general solution. As a local workaround on OS X, maybe it's possible to generate your own locale (see `localedef`) to match heroku's version of en_US.utf-8 (from glibc?).

Comment: update from postgres 11.  `en-US-x-icu` and `en-US-u-va-posix-x-icu` both appear in my `pg_collation` table, on Ubuntu 18.04 and macOS Mojave.  I did not have to do anything special at installation.  Applying them to existing columns is another question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57924382/how-to-change-column-collation-postgresql talks about it, but altering all columns individually doesnt sound like fun.