# Different ORDER BY behavior on localhost and production

Tags: postgresql

I found a problem with different ORDER BY behavior on my localhost and production DB.

I have on localhost PostgreSQL 9.3.5.1 and on production machine 9.5.5. Both are installed on Linux based systems - localhost is on OS X EL Captaion, production on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

On both machines I run following SQL query:

`SELECT title FROM projects ORDER BY title;`

And on both machines I get different result on same data sample.

Localhost:

```
!C project
A project
B project
```

Production:

```
A project
B project
!C project
```

So from some reason it looks like that PostgreSQL on production ignores "!" at the start of the title.

client_encoding and server_encoding settings are on both set to UTF8. lc_collate and similar settings are on both set to en_US.UTF-8.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370051/ordering-differences-between-postgres-instances-on-different-machines-same-loca and other similar

Comment: @VaoTsun Thank you! That one is little bit old, is there some solutions for that situation in these days to ensure same behavior on both systems?

Comment: It still just uses OS locale I think. Look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html and of course you can make workarounds

Comment: @DanielDimitrov you could try to run the console `sort` command on the linked question's answer to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Ubuntu do sorting different than Mac Os and Windows. It just ignores the `!` exclamation mark and sorts them normally by the second letter. You may search for [sort ubuntu exclamation](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=sort%20ubuntu%20exclamation).

1. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1564233
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/422708/how-to-show-some-files-at-the-top-of-the-list-in-ubuntu

Seems the PostgreSQL is being based on the sorting defined by the system.