# How to change column collation postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with default `LC_COLLATE=C` but I want to have different  `COLLATION` to one column in my table, how to do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can just alter column table

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN name SET DATA TYPE character varying(255) COLLATE "en_US"
```

Comment: much appreciated, +1.  however, for others reading this - it could be a little bit more complicated in practice.  On postgresql11, using an ICU collation, ALTER would not work because I had 2 views depending on the table.  So... drop views, alter, recreate views.

Comment: how could I set the default collation, please?