# Is it possible to have Python sort data the same was PostgreSQL does?

Tags: python, postgresql

My PostgreSQL DB appears to be using `en_US.UTF-8` collation:

```bash
# SHOW lc_collate;
 lc_collate  
-------------
 en_US.UTF-8
```

If I have a list of strings like: `['C - test', 'Common Scope']`, and I sort them in Python, I get:

```py
sorted(['C - test', 'Common Scope'])
['C - test', 'Common Scope']
```

but in Postgres, I get the opposite order:

```bash
# select * from TEST ORDER BY name;
     name     
--------------
 Common Scope
 C - test
```

Having Postgres sort the same way as Python does seems to be achievable by adding `COLLATE "C"` to the end of the select.

Is it possible to go the other way, and have Python sort strings the same was as Postgres does?

Comment: [Are you on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370051/ordering-differences-between-postgres-instances-on-different-machines-same-loca/13370762#13370762)

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL, what version of Python? I cannot reproduce your problem: MacOS 12.6, PostgreSQL 14.6, Python 3.8.1. Though [I can on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bI-Bcedt).

Comment: PostgreSQL 13.4, Python 3.9.7. Both on Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the Python [locale](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/locale.html) module. Also the [functools.cmp_to_key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) function:

```
import locale
from functools import cmp_to_key

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
locale.getlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')

sorted(['C - test', 'Common Scope'], key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll))
['Common Scope', 'C - test']
```

See [Comparison Operators](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#comparison-functions) for more information. The important part is:

> It is common to encounter comparison functions when translating algorithms from other languages. Also, some libraries provide comparison functions as part of their API. For example, locale.strcoll() is a comparison function.

> To accommodate those situations, Python provides functools.cmp_to_key to wrap the comparison function to make it usable as a key function:

> sorted(words, key=cmp_to_key(strcoll))  # locale-aware sort order